# Authorizes anyone with empty username while LDAP binding with credential

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am working on authorizing users using LDAP connection. Following is the small snap of the code

```
string principalUserName = "";
NetworkCredential NC = new NetworkCredential(principalUserName, password); 
LdapConnection.Bind(NC);`
```

The above code should have given error cause of the empty string but it doesn't. So as long as the `principalUserName` is empty, it will authorize anyone regardless of the password (hence `LdapConnection.Bind(NC)` won't give any error).

The appropriate value of principalUsername is in format like

```
CN=user1,OU=PublicOrganization
```

My question is: why is it authorizing an empty username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It treats empty credentials as no credentials. If you don't provide credentials, it uses the credentials of the running process.

So it's using your credentials.

You can test this by running your program under a local computer account, which won't be trusted by the domain. In that case, the test would fail.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. It makes sense now.